# I'm fairly new to TypeScript, and have been encountering an error: Unexpected token 'export'

Tags: typescript

I've been searching the internet but to no avail.

My code:

```
export const MESSAGES = {
    TEST: {
    ONE: 'Hello, world!'
  }
}
```

tsconfig:

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "target": "es6",
      "module": "commonjs",
      "strict": true
    }
  }
```

EDIT: I am requiring inside a JavaScript file.

Answer (score 1):

`export` keyword is es6 module syntax, so change `commonjs` to `esnext`.

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "target": "es6",
      "module": "esnext",
      "strict": true
    }
}
```

Comment: Nope. Changed accordingly, still getting same error. See my edited question

Comment: @user14428154 Can you give the full error info?